# Getting Facebook User Image on external website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering if there is a way to get the profile picture of a person visiting your website who is logged into Facebook.

**Practical Example**
I want to create a donor page. If the person donates it can show, for example,
their name and profile picture. I will ask their permission but I wanted to have it already
their and they just click yes.

I am guessing you have to create a "LOGIN thru Facebook" button on your page or grant permission thru and App. But I have no idea how to do any of this.

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: I am thinking this might be a step in the right direction? http://25labs.com/tutorial-integrate-facebook-connect-to-your-website-using-php-sdk-v-3-x-x-which-uses-graph-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st you need to create a facebook app in your facebook account and get the app ID and your secret code to connect to Facebook's api. This info can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Then wen a user logs in you use the api to get their user id. Once you have this you can use this code and put their id in the right place.

http://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/picture